# Create a Database Login to use for Web Application Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently completing an ASP.NET web app assignment which requires a n-tier design. On the marking guide for database design and implementation 1 mark goes towards:

**"A DB login created to use for the Web Application connection String"**

I've contacted my lecturer but no response about what I want to ask.

I have to hand in the SQL script as a script file. I'm wondering how do I create a DB login in the script? Or what does this mean when you read it.

Or am I over thinking this as I've already created a connection string and I've placed it in the web.config file which looks like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB; Id=myUsername;password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: [Create user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) might be a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="server=192.168.1.21\DBServer;database=DataBase1;user id=sa;pwd=wins123;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000;Connection Timeout=2000;"/>
    <add name="DBConnection1" connectionString="server=192.168.1.21\DBServer;database=DataBase2;user id=sa;pwd=wins123;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000;Connection Timeout=2000;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**server=192.168.1.21\DBServer** Instead of this you can put Your SQL Server Name

Comment: Thats not *creating* a login using a *script*